# Django URL tag not working with JS file, weird bug

Tags: javascript, django

Hobbyist here. Can't seem to figure out how to use the `{% url %}` static template with dynamic javascript.

For example, I am creating a list of days for a calendar where each day when clicked on should pull data from the database based on its date.

The day is being created dynamically in a loop, where the `href` attribute is being set for the URL.

My `<a href>` in the JS code looks like this currently for setting the URL:

```
aLink.setAttribute('href', currentYear + '-' + (currentMonth + 1) + '-' +dayCounter)
```

The problem with this method is this - Take a quick look at my URLS.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('<int:tutor_id>', views.tutorHomeOverviewPage, name='tutorHomeOverviewPage'), #homepage for when tutor/customer signs in
    path('<int:tutor_id>/<slug:selected_date>', views.tutorSelectedDay, name='tutorSelectedDay')
```

]

If I start off on a page which matches path 1 like so:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/tutorhomepage/7`
```

The code for the list item looks like this and doesn't point to a matching path because it removes the `/7` from the URL:

```
<a href="2022-10-17" id="day17">17</a>
```

Path:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/tutorhomepage/2022-10-14
```

Giving me the obvious error when I click on it:

```
Using the URLconf defined in sass_language_tutor_app.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

tutorhomepage/ <int:tutor_id> [name='tutorHomeOverviewPage']
tutorhomepage/ <int:tutor_id>/<slug:selected_date> [name='tutorSelectedDay']
admin/
The current path, tutorhomepage/2022-10-7, didn’t match any of these.
```

Now if I manually enter into the URL bar `7/`, before the date it works and the clicks match the second path and don't get rid of the `7/`.

No idea why this issue is occurring or how to fix it.

I want to use the {%url template%} which works when I make a static LI in the html file like so:

```
<a href="{% url 'tutorhomepage:tutorSelectedDay' tutor_id='7' selected_date='2022-10-16'%}">Date check test - click here</a>
```

The problem is when I try to do that in the JS file, it adds % signs and ampersands and makes the URL something its not. Making no path match.

Any idea of what is happening in this situation and what a possible solution could be?

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your url `<slug:selected_date>` you are telling Django that the url should contain a **Slug** and the date is not a slug, you are passing it as string so you need to make like this:

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('<int:tutor_id>', views.tutorHomeOverviewPage, name='tutorHomeOverviewPage'), #homepage for when tutor/customer signs in
    path('<int:tutor_id>/<str:selected_date>', views.tutorSelectedDay, name='tutorSelectedDay')
]
```

Comment: @B Okba, ill give it a try. Whats the difference then between a slug and a string, from the docs they look like the same thing to me, but maybe im missing something

Comment: sorry for late reply, `slug` is user-friendly URL, for example see your question in stackoverflow url and the title, you can see that the title `Django URL tag not working with JS file, weird bug` was converted to `django-url-tag-not-working-with-js-file-weird-bug`, that kind of conversion is "string to slug", kindly read more about "Slug URLs" to understand more about it, best regards.